# How to perform Core Data operations while the app is in background

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, cllocationmanager, multitasking

I have an iOS app enabled for "Location updates" Background Mode. I need to save part of the received `CLLocation` objects information with `Core Data` in order to send later some related information to a web service (also while the app running in background). I've made some tests of inserting and saving using the `NSManagedObjectContext` of the `AppDelegate` and in no separated thread, and it seems to work (at least running in the simulator). But I don't know if this is actually the appropiate way to do this. I've been looking for information regarding using `Core Data` while the app is in background state with no success.

My question is: is this safe? I mean, could my implementation cause any exception or conflicting state or loss related to `Core Data` and the information I want to save? Should I create a separated thread to handle this? Or what the best way to manage this scenario should be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are already playing the nice shot. Still my recomandations are :

1. Use `geofancing`. This will notify your app for selected change of range in locations.
2. I don't know why you asked to make a separate thread. Just enqueue the task in `dynamic dispatch`. Even if you want to make a separate thread. Fine.
3. Core data will definitely save while app is in background. This type of app can remain in background forever.
4. Use one Managed Object Context per thread. Managed object contexts are not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using location in background you can achieve saving of care data in background

First thing check if your app properly runs in background for location.
*Note : Don’t test it connecting to mac or debugging mode through cable.

Then in the below method if all goes well and application gets location.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

Add values in Core data

If you are having different viewController to save data, fire location notification and add observer to the add value in core data